# Leaflet polyline precision loss on zoom out

Tags: javascript, leaflet

When drawing multiple polylines, and zooming out the map, the line starts creating circles on vertexes:

[image: Zoomed in]

[image: Zoomed out]

[image: Zoomed out more]

The lines are being draw as follows:

```
L
    .polyline(line, {weight: 4, color: color, smoothFactor: 0, offset:offset})
    .addTo(Window.map);
```

I have tried with different values for the smoothFactor and offset with little difference. Why are the circles only visible when the map is not fully zoomed in? Can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies in the Leaflet.PolylineOffset plugin, I have created a new pull request which hopefully fixes it or at least serves as a basis to a better solution.
https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineOffset/pull/21

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you apply a pixel offset to the polylines.

When you zoom out, the vertices of your polyline become so close from each other that the offset algorithm determines directions for applying the offset much further than the general trend, leading to these funny circles.